# PostgreSql problem when querying large tables

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

What are the best tunning ideas to improve querying in large tables? I have a table of 500 millions rows in which if I run a query based on date range for the entire table, the execution time is over 30 - 40 minutes. I have a b-tree index on timestamp column that is used when running EXPLAIN ANALYZE. The work_mem is on 1GB, effective_cache_size is 9GB, sharred_buffers is 4 GB, random_page_cost = 1.1, RAM is 16GB, 4 Cores.

Comment: This might be better over at dba.stackexchange.com like [this question/answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39589/optimizing-queries-on-a-range-of-timestamps-two-columns).

Comment: The query is on topic, but please add the table definition, the query and the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for the query. Then we can give you a good answer.